# I have some problems with DrawerLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I'm working with DrawerLayout in my program, and my program has only one activity, and many fragments. When I open new fragment how can I block DrawerLayout, and when I close the fragment(back to HomePage) how can I unblock the DrawerLayout, please help me choose correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please lock it with

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

and unlock with

```
DrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Comment: What's cool is that if you have multiple drawers, then you can specify the "gravity" of the drawer that should be locked.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `drawer.setDrawerLockMode();` where the inside parameter can be:

`DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED` or `DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED`

Comment: I should lock Drawer when each fragment will open, right?

Comment: after you open fragment, just do this command in your activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use drawer.setDrawerLockMode(); where the inside parameter can be:

DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED or DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED